# Python warning: plotly.graph_objs.Line is deprecated

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Although everything works fine, I would like to know whether there is a way to fix what is provoking this warning:

> plotly.graph_objs.Line is deprecated. Please replace it with one of the following more specific types
>
> - plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line
> - plotly.graph_objs.layout.shape.Line
> - etc.

Comment: Ok. I learned I can edit the packages by myself (newbie python user here). I used the suggestion provided by the warning message.

Comment: Would you care to share exactly what you did? Maybe write it up as a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the warning regarding deprecated functions may variate, depending on the packages at use.
In my particular case, I was using the "Line" function from "plotly" package. This function was being called from another package. In the latter package there was a .py file (I used "IDLE (Python 3.8 64-bit)" to edit it) that had the following code line:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Line
```

Then, I first tried replacing that line with the suggestions provided by the warning. After a couple of tries, I ended up using the code line:

```
from plotly.graph_objs.scatter.marker import Line
```

My final script works fine like in the beginning, but this time with no warnings at all.

**Note:** In my case, the packages were installed in "C:\Users\NIP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages"

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

For me, replacing `go.Line` with `go.Scatter` and appending `mode='lines'` did the trick. Didn't have to change anything else, and the warning is gone.

Example:

```
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(
    x=x, 
    y=y_upper_limit, 
    name='Upper Bound', 
    marker=dict(
      color="Red"
    ),
    mode='lines',
    fill='tonexty',
    fillcolor='rgba(167, 167, 167, 0.12)',
  )
)
```